# OGR integer type to PostgreSQL BIGINT?

Tags: postgis, ogr

I have a problem with integer types when importing a shapefile created in OGR into PostGIS.

I started off with a field created as `ogr.OFTInteger64` in OGR/pyqgis as follows:

```
field_defn = ogr.FieldDefn( fld, ogr.OFTInteger64 ) 
lyr.CreateField ( field_defn )
```

The field type shows as type: `qlonglong`, and type name: `Integer64` in QGIS.

But after importing the shapefile into PostGIS with `shp2pgsql`,

```
shp2pgsql -Id -s 4326 my_lyr.shp my_lyr | psql
```

the field ended up being a `double precision` field in `\d+`, and I had to convert values in this field back to `BIGINT` before use.

According to [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-numeric.html), both `bigint` and `double precision` are types 8 byte (64 bit). How can I avoid the confusion and get the intended `BIGINT` field in PostGIS?

Comment: What happens if you use ogr2ogr for the conversion?

Comment: I guess if worst comes to worst, you can pipe the output from shp2pgsql through sed to fix the column definitions...

Comment: Can you provide a test shapefile?

Comment: What version of gdal are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick look into this, `CreateField` is a wrapper around C++'s Layer_CreateField. You can see that [bFID64 is supported in the pgdatasource](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/ddbf6d39aa4b005a77ca4f27c2d61a3214f336f8/gdal/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/pg/ogrpgdatasource.cpp#L1950). Perhaps you should check out `ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL"` instead of using `shp2pgsql`.

PostGIS provides `shp2pgsql` (not GDAL): it seems to not support 64 bit ints yet, and [instead defaults to FTDouble](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/svn-trunk/loader/shp2pgsql-core.c#L1355). You can see [all the types supported here](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/38f020842df6430f6162acf56e4e3b954ae94db3/loader/shp2pgsql-core.c#L1179) or [here](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/bd3177743db5cb786deb05d7327f39a5cec2daf6/loader/shapefil.h#L528). You can see the function that [sets the types here](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/33679ff52a4937d9e0f1bbaafb08aa3e675b2a72/loader/dbfopen.c#L1213).

**Update**, [I opened a bug report](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/3832#ticket)

These two code bases seem to have a lot of overlap. Because gdal is used by PostGIS, it seems that PostGIS should work to get their changes to the ogr data source merged upstream and maintained there.

Comment: FYI, `ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL"` generated a different error: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254671  @user30184